# Video Element - Skip Multiple Sections

Tags: html5-video

Using the `<video />` element, I'm trying to skip multiple sections of a video. I know I can attach a query string to the video url to set a start and stop time, but is there a way to set multiple start/stop times? For example, with these start and stop times

```
[{ start: 10, end: 22 },
{ start: 25, end: 30 },
{ start: 34, end: 40 }]
```

... can a video video play from 10s to 22s then skip ahead and play the next section (25s to 30s)?

```
<video id="video" controls>
   <source 
      src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4#t=10,22" 
      type="video/mp4"></source>
```

I tried playing around with different events to see if I could listen for the position and then skip ahead to my next starting time and `play()` the video, but so far nothing is working.

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: _"I tried playing around with different events to see if I could listen for the position..."_ Yeah that's your best chance. Listen for **timeupdate** event and use an `IF` statement to check the **video.currentTime** value against the required time (from the array).

Comment: PS: **(1)** You'll have to ask a new question but if you show the code of your attempt with event listeners I will try to fix it. **(2)** Also not clear if your  `[ times ]` array exists on the page itself (as JS var) or as a string in the URL variables?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I closed this as a duplicate. I found a very similar approach to what I was going for